# Android Gradle excluding jar from APK

Tags: android, jar, dependencies, gradle

Gradle appears to be excluding one of the jars I have listed in the dependencies of my Android project. All the projects are included correctly, as well as everything else except this one jar. Perhaps it's something wrong with the jar, but the project builds just fine.

The jar which is excluded was built from this project: https://github.com/pardom/InAppBillingLibrary

I used apktool (https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to have a look at the resulting apk, and none of the classes from that jar are included.

Here's my Gradle build file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    compile fileTree('libs')
    compile project(':libraries:ActionBarSherlock:actionbarsherlock')
    compile project(':libraries:AndroidUtils')
    compile project(':libraries:AndroidCommon')
    compile project(':libraries:ChartView:library')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion '17.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the jar is **not** compiled with Java 1.7. Try recompiling it using Java 1.5 or 1.6.

Currently, Android can't handle any Java 1.7 compiled classes.

Comment: @MichaelPardo Lucky for you I had the same problem only two days ago ;)